# How do you find a given array's children?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

Basically, I have the following array (or JSON):

```
apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
}
```

Is there any way to determine how many children does the array have?
E.g. in this case the answer is `2`: **app1** & **app2**. And if we add one more object "**application**" the answer will be `3`. I tried the following:

```
apps.length
//returns "undefined"

for (i = 0; apps[i] != undefined; i++) {
    console.log(apps[i]);
    //also returns "undefined"
    //I am later gonna use also the values in the child, so I stored all the children to a new array
    meta.push(apps[i]); //"meta" here is another vriable with an array in it
}
```

(if this makes any sense)
I expected the `for` to return something like this:

> **app1**
>   **app2**
> **application** (if you count the new object we added)
>
> And the value of `meta` to be `["app1", "app2", "application"]`.

My mind got totally obfuscated. I've got no idea where and what I am doing wrong, so any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks in advance!

**EDIT:**
If there is some way to `push()` elements into `apps` I will kindly ask you to light me up. Thanks again!

Comment: `apps` is not an array, nor is it JSON - it's an [object literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following

```js
let apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
}

let result = Object.keys(apps).length;

console.log(result);
```

here Object.keys() would return an array of all keys in the object. You simply need the length of this array which would give you the total number of keys in the object

You can assign properties to this object in the following way

```js
let apps = {
    app1:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Unnamed",
        "<h1>Hello world!</h1>"
    ],
    app2:
    [
        "ci-extension",
        "Another one!",
        "Cool!"
    ],
}

apps['app3'] = ["test"];
let result = Object.keys(apps).length;
console.log(result);
// or the following way
let objectToPush = {app4: ['test2']};
Object.assign(apps, objectToPush);
console.log(Object.keys(apps));
console.log(Object.keys(apps).length);
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer! I asked for 3 things and this is gonna help me solve 'em all! You are great!

Comment: see the updated answer